# No variables shown in eclipse debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I saw many similar questions, but the solution was not found, so i'm asking:

When i'm debuging the my android app NONE of the variables are shown in the "Variables" window. The console shows me that the debuger is not fully loaded.

```
[2012-02-21 22:23:29 - Watcher] Android Launch!
[2012-02-21 22:23:29 - Watcher] adb is running normally.
[2012-02-21 22:23:29 - Watcher] Performing com.workspace.watcher.WatcherActivity activity launch
[2012-02-21 22:23:29 - Watcher] Automatic Target Mode: using device 'F4559C737D65'
[2012-02-21 22:23:32 - Watcher] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2012-02-21 22:23:32 - Watcher] Starting activity com.workspace.watcher.WatcherActivity on device F4559C737D65
[2012-02-21 22:23:33 - Watcher] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.workspace.watcher/.WatcherActivity }
[2012-02-21 22:23:34 - Watcher] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.workspace.watcher' on port 8601
```

What is the problem? How can i fix it?

Comment: I guess you have several adb connections opened. That's why it cannot attach a debugger. Try to close all adb connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with Chorche in chat we determined that the problem was he did not set any breakpoints and as such there were no available variables to read.

This seems to be a pretty good explanation / tutorial on debugging using eclipse: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html